# Are there module level variables in Python?

Tags: python, scope

I am writing in caller script:

```
from XXX import config

....

config.limit = limit
data.load_data()
```

where `config.py` has

```
limit = None
```

inside and `data.py` has

```
from .config import *
...
def load_data():
    ...
    if limit is not None:
        limit_data(limit)
```

I was expecting everybody is refering the same varibale `limit` in `config.py` module. Unfortunately, I see while debygging, that `load_data` sees `None` limit, despite the fact it was set before.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `from .config import *`, you are importing a copy of `limit` from `config` into your own namespace. The `limit` entity that resides in `config` is not the same as the one you import. They reside in their own respective namespaces and are independent of each other.

As a workaround for this, consider this example:

`A.py`

```
foo = 5

def print_foo():
    print(foo)
```

`B.py`

```
import A

A.foo = 10
A.print_foo()
```

Now, running `B.py` should give:

```
$ python B.py
10
```

Meaning, you can refer to the same variable by prepending the namespace qualifier.

For relative imports, you'd do something similar:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    A.py
    B.py
```

In `B.py`, you'd call `import app.A`. You'd then refer to the variable as `app.A.limit`.

Comment: How to have one? Or how to refer one?

Comment: You'll change from `.config import *` to import `.config`. Then, if I'm not mistaken, referring to `config.limit` will refer to the same item.

Comment: @Dims Added an example.

Comment: Neither `import config`, nor `import .config` works. First complains "no module config", second complains "Invalid syntax"

Comment: @Dims Edited my answer. That should help.